# Logarithm in complex plane (Spot my mistake)

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

Please spot my mistake,

$$
\begin{align}
0&=0\\
\log(1)&=\log(1)\\
\log((-1)^2)&=\log(1)\\
2\log(-1)&=\log(1)\\
2\pi i&=0
\end{align}
$$

Actually somestimes i confused with $\log$ and $\ln$. What is the difference? Is $\log$ a logarithm with base of $10$ or $e$?

Comment: In any context that uses $\ln$ it is safe to assume $\log$ means base $10$. In some areas though people use $\log$ for the natural logarithm. In any case the error is that you assumed $\log(z^2)=2\log(z)$ holds for $z<0$; it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real numbers $x$,

1. $\log(x^2) = 2\log|x|$

and

2. $\ln(\cdot) := \log_e(\cdot)$ whereas $\log(\cdot) := \log_{10}(\cdot)$

Although for (2), popular sources such as wolfram define $\log(\cdot)$ as $\log_e(\cdot)$. The complex logarithm $\log(z)$ also assumes a base of $e$. Knowing the context and source is important.

Comment: Also, many older texts and old school mathematicians use $\log$ as the natural logarithm instead of $\ln$. In any case, it is safe to assume $\log$ is the natural logarithm unless otherwise specified (or the base is obvious within the context e.g. computer programming uses $\log_2$)